# How to Design a slideout menu in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Morning Every one
i am new to xamarin.forms and i am using visual studio 2017 to develop a cross platform mobile apple.

i created a master detail page  so that i can use a slide  navigation menu.

The slide navigation works but i needs an enhancement on it.

Below is the screen shot of what i have done

[image outut form code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyBab.png)

Below is my code

```
<MasterDetailPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               Title="first page"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.ContactPage" IsPresented="True">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage  Padding="0, 20, 0, 0" Title="Contact">
        <Image Source="icon.png"/>
        <ListView   x:Name="ListView" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<TextCell  Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}"  />-->
               
                    <TextCell  Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage>
        <Image Source="icon.png"/>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

```
  public partial class ContactPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public ContactPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListView.ItemsSource = new List<Contact>
        {
            new Contact{Name = "Home", ImageUrl = "http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/sports/1"},
            new Contact{Name = "About", ImageUrl = "http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/sports/2", Status = "feelgood"}
        };
    }

  //  async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
      void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var contact = e.SelectedItem as Contact;
        if (contact.Name == "Home")
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new GreetPage());
        }
        else
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContactDetailPage(contact));
        }
       
        IsPresented = false;

        // if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        //     return;
        // var contact = e.SelectedItem as Contact;
        //await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactDetailPage(contact));
        // ListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

Below is my expected output image

[Expected Image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxoc0.png)

Comment: In your case it would be better to use Shell with custom flyout . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout

Comment: though it seems you are new here but always modify your question very well

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not straight forward but i should be able to answer it.
You need thress things to complete the task.

1. Create a model
2. Create a Masterdetail using the template
3. Create your slides pages.
   Remove all the Pages that comes with it like MasterDetailPageMaster, MasterDetailPageDetail and MasterDetailPageMenuItem. After that change the  “MasterDetailPage” to MainPage.

   ```
        <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="MobileHMO.MainPage"
                     xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MobileHMO">
            <MasterDetailPage.Master>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu"
                         BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8">

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                        <StackLayout.Children >
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Header}" />

                            <Image HeightRequest="150" Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="Fill" />

                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Footer}" />
                        </StackLayout.Children>

                        <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
                          RowHeight="55"
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"
                          ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>


                                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                                     Padding="20,10,0,10"
                                     Spacing="20">

                                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                                 WidthRequest="40"
                                 HeightRequest="40"
                                 VerticalOptions="Start" />

                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                 FontSize="Small"
                                 VerticalOptions="End"
                                 TextColor="Black"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>

                    </StackLayout>

                </ContentPage>
            </MasterDetailPage.Master>

            <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
                <NavigationPage>

                </NavigationPage>
            </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        </MasterDetailPage>
   ```

   public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
   {
   private List menuList;

   ```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();


        var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Enrollee Profile", Icon = "enrollee.jpg", TargetType = typeof(view) };
        var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Dependants", Icon = "dependant.jpg", TargetType = typeof(view2) };
        var page3 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Bill Limit", Icon = "bills.jpg", TargetType = typeof(view3) };
        };

        menuList.Add(page1);
        menuList.Add(page2);
        menuList.Add(page3);
        menuList.Add(page4);
        menuList.Add(page5);
        menuList.Add(page6);
        menuList.Add(page7);
        menuList.Add(page8);
        menuList.Add(page9);

        // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml
        navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;
        // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnrolleeProfile)));
        this.BindingContext = new
        {
            Header = " Mobile",
            Image = "rina.png",
            //Footer = "         -------- Welcome   --------           "
            Footer = "Welcome "
        };
    }
   ```

   }